# WP7/Silverlight How do you toggle a checkbox inside a list?

Tags: windows-phone-7, .net-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I'm having issues trying to figure this out.  Basically, I have a listbox with a checkbox in it, making it a "Checked" listbox.

What I want to do is when a user hits a button, the checkbox is toggled (either shows or hides).

I've tried binding the visibility to a property in my view model but that isn't work.

What is the correct way to go about this?  I've searched google and SO and couldn't find anything solid.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some code? It's hard to tell what's going wrong just from your description.

Answer (score 0):

Bind visibility of the checkbox to a property of the class contained in the list that is the items source of the listbox.

Here is some code. This was a quick test and uses code behind but should be easily ported to your view model.

Class:

```
public class CheckString
{
    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get 
        { 
            Visibility retval = Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (IsChecked)
            {
                retval = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public CheckString() {}
}
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public List<CheckString> CheckStringList { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetupList();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void SetupList()
    {
        CheckStringList = new List<CheckString>();

        CheckString cs1 = new CheckString { Description = "Test 1"};
        CheckStringList.Add(cs1);

        CheckString cs2 = new CheckString { IsChecked = true, Description = "Test 2" };
        CheckStringList.Add(cs2);

        CheckString cs3 = new CheckString { Description = "Test 3" };
        CheckStringList.Add(cs3);

    }

}
```

Xaml

```
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <CheckBox
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />

                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: How is this going to set the visibility of the checkbox?  I want to show or hide the checkbox's in the list.

Comment: Sorry - misread the question. Have posted example code that meets your requirements.